# Android application to show the battery charging rate (e.g. in mA)

Tags: android, battery

I am looking for an Android application that can show the battery charging rate (e.g. in mA).

Free is better, but paid OK too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Battery Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ccc71.bmw) will show that.

It has the ability to show it as a widget as well as in-app. It's also free (with ads)
It's pretty simple to use. I only used it for a short while but it does what you need.

The feature to show charging rate is a free feature.

[image: app screenshot]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

Answer (score 3):

[CurrentWidget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.manor.currentwidget) also provides the charging information as a widget, and is also free.

CurrentWidget can also stay in your notifications bar to provide information, as well as provide alerts when the phone is using *above* a certain amount of power which I liked. Didn't really have any cons about them when I was using them.

Comment: Thanks though I won't try it: "This app is incompatible with all of your devices." :/

Comment: That sucks. Are your devices older devices ?

Comment: I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2, a Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2 and a Samsung I9100 Galaxy S II with Android 2.3, surprising none of them is compatible according to Play (I could try to install the apk directly but anyway Battery Monitor seems to do the job).

Answer (score 3):

Another popular alternative: [Ampere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gombosdev.ampere).

> Measure the charging and discharging current of your battery.
>
> PRO features:
>
> - Widgets
> - Notification
> - Alerts on device
> - Alerts on Android Wear

Answer (score 1):

[Galaxy Charging Current Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.abmantis.galaxychargingcurrent.free) is another app that will show the battery charging rate.

Works on my SGS3.

Answer (score 1):

FOSS apps:

- ACCA requires root, but also able to limit charge current, target charge voltage. [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/mattecarra.accapp/). I personally use it to cycle my battery between 20-80 % to prolong it's lifespan.
- BatteryBot Pro (only Pro version, current sensing [disabled](https://github.com/darshan-/Battery-Indicator-Support/blob/master/FAQ.wiki#why-doesnt-the-current-ma-show-up-by-default--why-doesnt-it-work-on-my-device) by default). [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro&hl=en&gl=US), [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.darshancomputing.BatteryIndicatorPro/).